# Find a first integral of an ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, integrating-factor

I have the system

$$ \left\{\begin{aligned}
\dot x & = 2xy \\
\dot y & = x+y^2 \\
\end{aligned}\right. $$

and I need to find a first integral $H$ of the system. This is easy if the equation $$\left( x + y^2 \right) {\rm d} x - 2 x y \, {\rm d} y = 0$$ is exact, i.e., if the divergence of the field is $0$. In this case, the divergence is $4y$ so I need to find an integrating factor $\mu(x,y) $, but I don't know how to do it, because it doesn't work if I use that $\mu$ is just a function of $x$ or $y$. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Answer (score 4):

Collect terms in the differential form and combine them into differentials of increasingly complex functions to reduce the number of terms,
$$
0=\frac12d(x^2)+y^2dx - xd(y^2)=\frac12d(x^2)-x^2d(\frac{y^2}x).
$$
With $u=x^2$ and $v=\frac{y^2}{x}$ this reads as
$$
0=\frac12du-udv=-u\,d\!\left(-\frac12\ln u+v\right),
$$
which gives $F=-\frac12\ln u+v=-\ln|x|+\frac{y^2}x$ as first integral. Test by differentiating along a solution
$$
\frac{dF}{dt}=-\frac{\dot x}{x}-\frac{y^2\dot x}{x^2}+\frac{2y\dot y}{x}
=-2y-\frac{2y^3}{x}+\frac{2y(x+y^2)}{x}=0
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y^2}{2xy}$$
$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=1+\frac{y^2}{x}$$
Let $Y=y^2$
$$\frac{dY}{dx}=1+\frac{Y}{x}$$
This is a first order linear ODE easy to solve.
$$Y=x\ln|x|+cx$$
$$y=\pm\sqrt{x\ln|x|+cx}$$