# Trouble of understanding solution about ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, chain-rule

In the question [Find a first integral of an ODE system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058787), there is following system of equations:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\dot x=2xy \\ 
\dot y=x+y^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Second answer solved for $y$. I have question about this solution.

As far as I know $x$ and $y$ are some functions of let's say $t$. So I can rewrite system:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x'(t)=2x(t)y(t) \\ 
y'(t)=x(t)+(y(t))^2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I will do the same as in the answer however I will keep track of variable $t$

$$\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=\frac{x(t)+(y(t))^2}{2x(t)y(t)}$$

$$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{x(t)+(y(t))^2}{2x(t)y(t)}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x(t)+(y(t))^2}{2x(t)y(t)}$$

$$y'(x(t))=\frac{x(t)+(y(t))^2}{2x(t)y(t)}$$

$$2y(t)y'(x(t))=1+\frac{(y(t))^2}{x(t)}$$

Substitute $Y(t)=(y(t))^2$

$$\frac{dY}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dY}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=2y(t)\frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}=2y(t)\frac{dy}{dx}=2y(t)y'(x(t))$$

So:

$$\frac{dY}{dx}=1+\frac{Y(t)}{x(t)}$$

$$Y'(x(t))=1+\frac{Y(t)}{x(t)}$$

The author of solution claims that this is first order linear ODE, but on left side there is $Y'(x(t))$ and on right $Y(t)$ not $Y(x(t))$ or $Y'(t)$ on left. So I am not sure about this.

Author says that:

$$Y=x\ln|x|+cx$$

What i $Y$? Is it $Y(t)$ or $Y(x(t))$ or something else? I think it should be $Y(t)$ but then I think on the right side there should be $1+\frac{Y(x(t))}{x(t)}$ Did I make mistake in my notation?

Comment: In my opinion $Y$ is $Y$ and all of these are $Y$: $Y, Y(t), Y(y(t)), Y(x(t))$. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $x\to Y(x)$ is such that $Y(x(t))=y^2(t)$.
Then, after taking the derivative with respect to $t$ of both sides we find $$Y'(x(t))x'(t)=2y(t)y'(t)$$
and it follows that
$$\frac{2y(t)y'(t)}{x'(t)}=1+\frac{(y(t))^2}{x(t)}
\implies Y'(x(t))=1+\frac{Y(x(t))}{x(t)}.$$
By solving the linear ODE $Y'(x)=1+\frac{Y(x)}{x}$, we get $Y(x)=x\ln|x|+cx$ and therefore
$$y^2(t)=x(t)\ln|x(t)|+cx(t)$$
or, after removing the parameter $t$,
$$y^2=x\ln|x|+cx.$$

P.S. See also this [Desmos page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/j6fmqrtxyb): the red curve (depending on the constant $c$) is the solution in the (normalized) vector field.

Comment: Thank you. To the desmos part, should I pay attention to something particular?

Comment: The red curve (depending on the constant $c$) is the solution in the (normalized) vector field